# Displaying list under tabbed view

Tags: android, list, view, tabs

I'm trying to display a custom list under a tab in a tabbed view.
my code is here:

```
**manifest:**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.clinical.testapp"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <activity android:name="com.clinical.testapp.ArtistsActivity" />
            <activity android:name="com.clinical.testapp.AlbumsActivity" />
            <activity android:name="com.clinical.testapp.SongsActivity" />
            <activity android:name="com.clinical.testapp.DatabaseActivity" />
            <activity android:name="com.clinical.testapp.AppsManager" />
            <activity android:name="com.clinical.testapp.AppListActivity" />

            <activity android:name=".HelloTabWidget" android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
              <intent-filter>
                     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                 </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        </application>

    </manifest>

**main.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                 >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:padding="20dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>

**app_row.xml:**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="30dp"
         android:padding="6dip">
         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/icon"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
         <LinearLayout
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="0dip"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/toptext"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:gravity="center_vertical"
             />
             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1" 
                 android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
                 android:singleLine="true"
                 android:ellipsize="marquee"
             />
         </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

**HelloTabWidget.java:**

    package com.clinical.testapp;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.TabActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.ScrollView;
    import android.widget.TabHost;

    public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
            TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
            Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

            // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);
            // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                    .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            // Do the same for the other tabs
            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
                    .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
                    .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DatabaseActivity.class);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("DB").setIndicator("DB",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_db))
                    .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AppsManager.class);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Apps").setIndicator("Apps",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_apps))
                    .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Appslist").setIndicator("Appslist",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_applist));
            spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory(){
                public View createTabContent(String tag)
                {
                 // -- this tab contains a single control - the listview -- //


                    /*  ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(HelloTabWidget.this);
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams svLp = new ScrollView.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

                    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(HelloTabWidget.this);
                    ll.setLayoutParams(svLp);
                    */

                    ListView ls1 = new ListView(HelloTabWidget.this);
                    //ls1.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,ListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                    ArrayList<App> m_apps = new ArrayList<App>();
                    App a1 = new App();
                    a1.setAppName("SF services");
                    a1.setAppDesc("Pending");
                    App a2 = new App();
                    a2.setAppName("SF Advertisement");
                    a2.setAppDesc("Completed");
                    m_apps.add(a1);
                    m_apps.add(a2);
                    m_apps.add(new App("app3 name","app3 desc"));
                    AppAdapter m_adapter = new AppAdapter(HelloTabWidget.this, R.layout.app_row, m_apps);
                   ls1.setAdapter(m_adapter);
                   ls1.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(HelloTabWidget.this);
                   return ls1;
                   /*
                   ll.addView(ls1);
                   sv.addView(ll);
                   return sv;
                   */
    //                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    //                      HelloTabWidget.this,
    //                       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    //                       new String[]{"item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6","item7"});
    //                
    //                
    //                 ls1.setAdapter(adapter); 
    //                 ls1.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(HelloTabWidget.this);
    //                 return ls1;
                }         
           });


            /*
            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AppsListActivity.class);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Appslist").setIndicator("Appslist",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_applist))
                    .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);
            */

            tabHost.addTab(spec);


            for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++) {
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = 133;
            } 

            tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
        }
    }

**and AppAdapter.java:**

    package com.clinical.testapp;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<App> {

             private ArrayList<App> items;

             public AppAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<App> items) {
                     super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
                     this.items = items;
             }

             @Override
             public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                     View v = convertView;
                     if (v == null) {
                         LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                         v = vi.inflate(R.layout.app_row, null);
                     }
                     App app = items.get(position);
                     if (app != null) {
                             TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                             TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
                             if (tt != null) {
                                   tt.setText("Name: "+app.getAppName());                            }
                             if(bt != null){
                                   bt.setText("Status: "+ app.getAppDesc());
                             }
                     }
                     return v;
             }
    }
```

but the result of the list is:
I cannot see the whole list, it's somehow stop displaying the rest of the list.
Please helpp!!
Thanks, Bush

Comment: what we have to do with this code? provide xml layout files

Comment: i provided all the code i had, you just needed to scroll it down. btw, i solved that problem ,see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my problem, it was in the main.xml.
i've should done the  and  insisde the ! not outside!
I've wasted much hours on it and i'm glad to share the answer!
gr8 day!
Bush.